# WPF Window Maximized causes Items to be misplaced

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I have set my WPF window to be maximized however the items inside it, such as buttons and images are sometimes stretched along with the window or even the positions are misplaced.

```
<Window x:Class="HelloApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="HelloApp" Height="661.842" Width="1105.263"
    WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Background="#FFF3F3F3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <Label Content="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
        <Image Margin="49,7,994,593" Source="Infinite_symbol__128.png"/>
        <Button x:Name="exitBtn" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1042.148,9.606,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52.852" Height="51" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="exitBtn_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="close33 (2).png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For example, if Button X is at the top left corner in my Editor when I startup the program it would remain at the editor's top left, however the when maximized the actual top left would be much further apart.

I hope you understand what I mean. I want my child items to maximize along with the parent. How can I edit my code to get this done?

Comment: Put your layout codes include `container element`, `button`, `editor` and... here, your answer will be base on your current window layout. how others can help you when there is not any require info about your layout here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Grid` as main container of the window, don't modify its properties like `width` or... it keep grid fit to window. then click on each element and try playing with its anchors like `chain` on the `Grid` border in the `Xaml Designer`.

For example i fit your button on right top corner by set `right chain` sign and `top chain` sign of it in `close` mode and i `open`ed other `chains` of it.

[image]

```
   <Grid Background="#FFF3F3F3">
        <Label Content="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
        <Image  Source="Infinite_symbol__128.png" Margin="113,0,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="exitBtn" Content="Test"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"  Width="65" Height="51" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="exitBtn_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="close33 (2).png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Other way is using `columns` and `rows` for better layout BUT even when you use cols and rows you must set `anchor points` of your element inside the cell. This is the safe way to keep your elements in your ideal positions.

Comment: What do you mean 'chains'? I understand that those are the 4 chain icons attached to the window. So if I attach the chains to the window, it will maximize along with the window?

Comment: They are anchor points. They are related to your grid, not your window and each element has their 4 anchors in the grid. So If you want your element size change in X and Y (width & height) by changing window size (for example maximize window), then you should set all of anchor points (chains) on CLOSE mode. By this setting you say: I want my element change its size accourding the grid size, and the grid is fit to window and this is your target.

Comment: Ah nice. My question is, how do I set the anchor points for my text which is in the middle? Is there an option in the Properties dialog?

Comment: Now you say: "my text"...! But in your question you are speaking about keeping the  top corner Button position during maximize. I can't understand "my text" is which element or text of which element. Please change your question with adding new parts to explain your problem clearly. If you can take 2 snapeshot from your window, befor and after "maximize" then compare them and describe your problem base on the images.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Margins` you can define specific `Grid.RowDefinitions` and `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` depending on your desired layout. For example the following Xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="TopLeft"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="TopRight"/>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="BottomLeft" />
    <Button  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="BottomRight" />
</Grid>
```

divides your window this way:

[image]

In the above Xaml, `Auto` means "size to cell content" and `*` means "size to remaining area".